# carrierwave: mount uploader on serialized dynamic attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, metaprogramming, carrierwave

first of all, i am using rails 3.1.3 and carrierwave from the master 
branch of the github repo.

i use a after_init hook to determine fields based on an attribute of 
the page model instance and define attribute accessors for these field 
which store the values in a serialized hash (hope it's clear what i am 
talking about). here is a stripped down version of what i am doing:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base 
  serialize :fields, Hash 

  after_initialize :set_accessors 

  def set_accessors 
    case self.template 
      when 'standard' 
        class << self 
            define_method 'image' do 
              self.fields['image'] 
            end 
            define_method 'image=' do |value| 
              self.fields['image'] = value 
            end 
          end 
          mount_uploader :image,   PageImageUploader 
        end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

leaving out the mount_uploader command gives me access to the 
attribute as i want. but when i mount the uploader a get an error 
message saying 'undefined method new for nil class'

i read in the source that there are the methods read_uploader and 
write_uploader in the extensions module. 
how do i have to override these to make the mount_uploader command 
work with my 'virtual' attribute.

i hope somebody has an idea how i can solve this problem. thanks a lot 
for your help.

best regard. dominik.

Comment: This is a pretty localized question, so you may have better luck asking the CarrierWave group: http://groups.google.com/group/carrierwave

Comment: thanks for the reply but i tried that already. no answer sadly. that's why i came here.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem but solved in your model you should override `read_uploader(column)` and `write_uploader(column, identifier)` instance methods. I also have a problem with `#{column}_will_change!` and `#{column}_changed?` for a virtual column so I had to define them too:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :meta, Hash

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def image_will_change!
    meta_will_change!
    @image_changed = true
  end

  def image_changed?
    @image_changed
  end

  def write_uploader(column, identifier)
    self.meta[column.to_s] = identifier
  end

  def read_uploader(column)
    self.meta[column.to_s]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Now there's also an add-on to carrierwave which provides the exact functionality as described by Antiarchitect:

https://github.com/timsly/carrierwave-serializable